# SailsJS Resourceful PubSub - duplicated update messages

Tags: sockets, sails.js

I'm subscribing to a model updates using a custom action, relevant code below:

```
getCurrent: (req, res) => {
    Session.findOne({sessionStatus: 'in-progress'})
      .populate('participants')
      .populate('messages')
      .exec((err, session) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.json({
            error: err
          })
        }

        // check if we have any active (in-progress) session in database
        if(!session) {
          return res.json({
            error: { message: 'No in-progress session found.'}
          })
        }

        // subscribe our client socket to this record.
        if (req.isSocket) {
          Session.subscribe(req, session);
        }

        return res.json(session);
      });
  }
```

When updating Session model all works fine I get a single 'updated' message but when I add new message to session through **POST:/session/id/message** I'm receiving 'addedTo' message twice, not sure what I'm doing wrong. Using Sails 0.12.4 (latest).

Update:

Session model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    sessionName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    sessionStatus: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['created', 'in-progress', 'ended'],
      defaultsTo: 'created',
      required: true
    },
    activeCaseNo: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: false
    },
    currentScreen: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: false
    },
    participants: {
      collection: 'SessionParticipant',
      via: 'session',
      required: false
    },
    messages: {
      collection: 'SessionMessage',
      via: 'session',
      required: false
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: are you sending the POST through the websocket? Could you share how your Session model is defined in regards to messages?

Comment: @ChristopheAugier, POST to messages is XHR using Angular $resource

Comment: ok so there should not be any automatic subscription done by the post on the message if you are not creating a new resource through the websocket. Anyway it would not have been sent as a 'addedTo' message.